# Blackberry - Running Background Application

Tags: blackberry, process, background-application

Good afternoon.
I'm starting programming in java and blackberry.
I am developing an application with three windows, which I will show basic information about the device, these windows are already done and working.
I need to create a process running in the background, this process will run every 10 minutes.
As I make this process run in the background and is working to close the windows?

This is the kind that runs the application:

```
    public class InfoBerry extends UiApplication{
    public vtnprincipal vtnprincipal;
    public vtnbateria vtnbateria;
    public vtnestado vtnestado ;
    public vtnacerca vtnacerca;

    public InfoBerry(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            InfoBerry theApp = new InfoBerry();
            theApp.mostrarpantalla();
    }
    public void mostrarpantalla(){

        vtnprincipal = new vtnprincipal(this);
        vtnbateria = new vtnbateria(this);
        vtnestado = new vtnestado(this);
        vtnacerca = new vtnacerca(this);
        // Inicailizamos los componentes de la pantalla principal
        vtnprincipal.incventana();
        // La pnemos en lo alto de la pila de pantallas

        pushScreen(this.vtnprincipal);
        }
}
```

And this is the class you need to run in the background.
As I have to make the call to this class to run in the background?

```
class iconnoti extends MainScreen{
    //icono de la temperatura
    EncodedImage imgtem = 
            EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("icon_bateria_t.png");
    ApplicationIcon icontem = new ApplicationIcon(imgtem);
  //icono de la carga de la bateria
    EncodedImage imgcarga = 
            EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("icon_bateria.png");
    ApplicationIcon iconcarga = new ApplicationIcon(imgcarga);
    //icono de la memoria
    EncodedImage imgmemo = 
            EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("icon_memoria.png");
    ApplicationIcon iconmemo = new ApplicationIcon(imgmemo);
    ApplicationIcon mIcon = icontem;
    boolean act;
    public iconnoti() {


    }

    public void rotar_temperatura(){
        cron c1;
        actualizar_icono(icontem);
        actualizar_valor(DeviceInfo.getBatteryTemperature());

        c1 = new cron(2,10000);
        c1.start();


    }
    public void rotar_memoria(){
        cron c1;
        actualizar_icono(iconmemo);
        actualizar_valor(34);

        c1 = new cron(3,10000);
        c1.start();

    }
    public void rotar_nivel(){
        cron c1;
        actualizar_icono(iconcarga);
        actualizar_valor(DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel());
        c1 = new cron(1,10000);
        c1.start();

    }

   public void iniciar_servicio() {
       try {

           ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = 
                    ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
                ApplicationIndicator Indicator = 
                    reg.register(mIcon, false, true);
                } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public  void parar_servicio() {
        try {
                ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = 
                    ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
                reg.unregister();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    void actualizar_valor(int value) {
        try {
                ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = 
                    ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
                ApplicationIndicator appIndicator = 
                    reg.getApplicationIndicator();
                appIndicator.setValue(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    void actualizar_icono(ApplicationIcon icon) {
        try {
                ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = 
                    ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();
                ApplicationIndicator appIndicator = 
                    reg.getApplicationIndicator();
                appIndicator.setIcon(icon);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

class cron extends Thread {
    //private ApplicationIcon icono;
    public int valor;
    private int tiempo;
    iconnoti icon = new iconnoti();

    public cron(int v, int t){
        valor = v;
        tiempo = t;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(tiempo);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  

        }
        if(valor == 1){
            icon.rotar_temperatura();
        }else if(valor == 2){
            icon.rotar_memoria();
        }else if(valor == 3){
            icon.rotar_nivel();
        }

    }           

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Background Application is a kind of process, so there is no GUI at least on the beginning.

- You should extend Application instead of UIApplication class
- You should not push screen there, just move everything from iconnoti class to cron class and run it in Application constructor:

  ```
  public class BerryInfoApp extends Application {
      public BerryInfoApp() {
              UpdateThread updateThread = new UpdateThread(10*60*1000);
              updateThread.run();
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          (new BerryInfoApp()).enterEventDispatcher();
      }
  }

  class UpdateThread extends Thread {
  EncodedImage imgtem = EncodedImage
          .getEncodedImageResource("icon_bateria_t.png");
  ApplicationIcon icontem = new ApplicationIcon(imgtem);
  EncodedImage imgcarga = EncodedImage
          .getEncodedImageResource("icon_bateria.png");
  ApplicationIcon iconcarga = new ApplicationIcon(imgcarga);
  EncodedImage imgmemo = EncodedImage
          .getEncodedImageResource("icon_memoria.png");
  ApplicationIcon iconmemo = new ApplicationIcon(imgmemo);
  ApplicationIcon mIcon = icontem;

  static final int ACTION_NONE = 0;
  static final int ACTION_BATTERY_TEMP = 1;
  static final int ACTION_MEMORY = 2;
  static final int ACTION_BATTERY_LEVEL = 3;
  int mAction = ACTION_BATTERY_LEVEL;
  long mPeriod;

  public UpdateThread(int period) {
      mPeriod = period;
  }

  public void stop() {
      mAction = ACTION_NONE;
  }

  public void run() {
      iniciar_servicio();
      while (mAction != ACTION_NONE) {
          switch (mAction) {
          case ACTION_BATTERY_TEMP:
              rotar_temperatura();
              mAction = ACTION_MEMORY;
              break;
          case ACTION_MEMORY:
              rotar_memoria();
              mAction = ACTION_BATTERY_LEVEL;
              break;
          case ACTION_BATTERY_LEVEL:
              rotar_nivel();
              mAction = ACTION_BATTERY_TEMP;
              break;
          default:
              break;
          }
          try {
              sleep(mPeriod);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          }
      }
      parar_servicio();
  }

  public void rotar_temperatura() {
      actualizar_icono(icontem);
      actualizar_valor(DeviceInfo.getBatteryTemperature());
  }

  public void rotar_memoria() {
      actualizar_icono(iconmemo);
      actualizar_valor(34);
  }

  public void rotar_nivel() {
      actualizar_icono(iconcarga);
      actualizar_valor(DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel());
  }

  public void iniciar_servicio() {
      try {
          ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                  .getInstance();
          ApplicationIndicator Indicator = reg.register(mIcon, false, true);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
  }

  public void parar_servicio() {
      try {
          ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                  .getInstance();
          reg.unregister();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
  }

  void actualizar_valor(int value) {
      try {
          ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                  .getInstance();
          ApplicationIndicator appIndicator = reg.getApplicationIndicator();
          appIndicator.setValue(value);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
  }

  void actualizar_icono(ApplicationIcon icon) {
      try {
          ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                  .getInstance();
          ApplicationIndicator appIndicator = reg.getApplicationIndicator();
          appIndicator.setIcon(icon);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
  }
  }
  ```