# How to run BlackBerry application in Background

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am working on a BlackBerry Application which requires the application be running once its sent to the background also. 
I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me to any tutorials related to running background services in BlackBerry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background Application is a kind of process so you should extend Application instead of extending Uiapplication . In your main class implement all your code. You can also see this StackOverflow question for an example: [Blackberry - Running Background Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768171/blackberry-running-background-application)

Answer (score 1):

RIM has posted an article about running applications in background on their support forum:
[Make a running UI application go to the background and resume in the foreground](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Make-a-running-UI-application-go-to-the-background-and-resume-in/ta-p/445059)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alternate Entry Points to make your application run in the background. Check the link below for assistance

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23567/Always_on_1380986_11.jsp